# Reinstall UBUNTU without effecting windows

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, uninstall

I want to reinstall UBUNTU by removing it first without effecting my installed windows
note: my UBUNTU don't open .. it just gives me blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing or reinstalling Ubuntu shouldn't affect Windows in the lest, as long as it's not installed over the Windows partition. Boot into the Ubuntu installer, erase the *partition* (not the whole drive) that Ubuntu is installed on, and reinstall. There also should be the option to erase Ubuntu and reinstall, but if it isn't there, just do the above.

Comment: i will try that

Comment: any advice to avoid making harmful mistake?

Comment: Open Gparted in the LiveCD/USB and erase the Ubuntu `ext4` partition from there. _Leave the NTFS one intact!` Then go into the installer, choose Something Else... and select the erased partition as the install location (mount it as `/`).